# How to generate code in Visual Studio in the current document?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I apologize if this is something that is easily searched, but I'm not really sure what the correct search terms are for this.

I am using Visual Studio right now, primarily for Unity development.  When creating a new script, I often declare a some private member variables like this:

```
private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
private SomeOtherComponent _myComponent;
```

In order to initialize those variables, I need to add a GetComponent call in a function called "Start", like this:

```
void Start(){
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    _myComponent = GetComponent<SomeOtherComponent>();
}
```

Right now, I've found a Visual Studio snippet to quickly type the "GetComponent" part, which is nice, but I'm looking for a way to auto-generate the lines of code in the Start function.  In an ideal world, I could type in

```
private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
```

then I could hit some key-combination, and it would automatically add

```
_rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

To the Start function.

Snippets only get me halfway there.  What would I need to do to create this type of extension for Visual Studio?  Is this a difficult thing to accomplish?

Comment: ReSharper has this capability, but it isn't free.

Comment: There's also [snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx).

Comment: Why not have a snippet for the declarations and a snippet for the initializations?

Comment: Snippets let me type out the GetComponent line a bit faster, sure, but again they only get me halfway there.  I still have to declare my member variable, then go down to the Start function, and then type out my snippet.  I'm trying to skip that step.

Comment: You may look into Roslyn analyzers and code fixes (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix). Analyzer allows you detect the private fields to be initialized and popup a prompt to the developer. A codefix invoked by the prompt can generate the initialization code, Though it something that has its learning curve and will require a bit of effort. Let me know if you are interested in this direction and I will elaborate it into an answer.

Comment: @Amy Can you elaborate on what in Resharper I'd be looking for?  I don't see a way for a live template to add code to an existing function.  The "Start" function already exists, and I'm trying to automatically add a single line of code to it (probably at the top).  What part of Resharper does this?

Comment: @felix-b I'm a bit nervous about doing something too complex, since this is a thing that would save me 3-5 seconds per instance of this problem, so if I have to spend several hours figuring out a whole other tool, it may not be worth it for me, but I'd be interested in hearing more.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension which is designed exactly for such kind of lightweight extensibility. It allows to edit a document as text or use Visual Studio code model and Roslyn.

For example, call the following command when the caret is on _rigidbody or _myComponent in a variable declaration:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        this.DTE = DTE;

        EnvDTE.CodeVariable v = FindCurrentVariable();
        if (v != null)
        {
            string initialization = v.Name + " = GetComponent<" + v.Type.CodeType.Name + ">();";
            AddLine(FindFunction("Start"), initialization);
        }
    }

    EnvDTE.CodeFunction FindFunction(string name)
    {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        if (ts == null)
            return null;
        EnvDTE.CodeClass codeClass = ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass]
            as EnvDTE.CodeClass;
        if (codeClass == null)
            return null;
        foreach (EnvDTE.CodeElement elem in codeClass.Members)
        {
            if (elem.Kind == EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction && elem.Name == name)
                return elem as EnvDTE.CodeFunction;
        }
        return null;
    }

    EnvDTE.CodeVariable FindCurrentVariable()
    {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        if (ts == null)
            return null;
        return ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementVariable]
            as EnvDTE.CodeVariable;
    }

    void AddLine(EnvDTE.CodeFunction f, string text)
    {
        EnvDTE.TextPoint tp = f.GetStartPoint(EnvDTE.vsCMPart.vsCMPartBody);
        EnvDTE.EditPoint p = tp.CreateEditPoint();
        p.Insert(text + System.Environment.NewLine);
        p.SmartFormat(tp);
    }

    EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE;
}
```

Comment: Nice extension! I hope no one minds you mentioning it here, because it looks really useful. Trying it out now...